# Finding if a Linked List is a palindrome

Tags: c, linked-list, palindrome

I seperated the funcitons the reverse the list, find its length, and find if it it's palindrome.
Here is my code

```
int length(struct ListNode* head){
    if(head == NULL)
        return 0;
    else
        return (1+length(head->next));
}

struct ListNode* reverseList(struct ListNode* head){
    struct ListNode* prev = NULL;
    struct ListNode* next = NULL;
    struct ListNode* curr = head;
    while(curr!=NULL){
        next = curr->next;
        curr->next = prev;
        prev = curr;
        curr=next;
    }
    return prev;
}

bool isPalindrome(struct ListNode* head){
    int n = length(head);
    struct ListNode* curr = NULL;
    if(n%2==0){
        int a=n/2;
        curr = head;
        while(curr!=NULL &&  a!= 0){
            a--;
            curr = curr->next;
        }
    }
    else{
        int a=n/2 + 1;
        curr = head;
        while(curr!=NULL &&  a!= 0){
            a--;
            curr = curr->next;
        }
    }
    struct ListNode* node = reverseList(curr);
    while(curr!=NULL && head!=NULL){
        if(curr!=head)
            return false;
        curr = curr->next;
        head = head->next;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I have been trying to solve the problem "234. Palindrome Linked List" in LeetCode, I thought that I found the solution, but for some reason the function returns false in cases where it should return true. I tried to find the error but I couldn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues in your code:

1. Although you declare `node` to be the head of the reversed list, the loop that follows does not use that `node`, but continues to use `curr`, which now is the tail of the reversed list. Instead you should either use `node` in the loop, or else (saving space) assign the reversed list to `curr`.
2. The comparison `curr!=head` will always be true. You should compare the `val` members of the nodes, not their addresses.

So correct the relevant part like this:

```
    curr = reverseList(curr); // assign to `curr`
    while(curr!=NULL && head!=NULL){
        if(curr->val!=head->val) // compare `val`
            return false;
```